# Printf crashes in FASM

Tags: windows, assembly, fasm

The following code prints `30967` and crashes.

It is FASM on Windows 7 x86 (32bit).

Could someone please explain to me why it crashes?

```
format PE console
entry start
include 'win32a.inc'
pos00:
db 10,0,0,0
str2:
db '%d',0
h:
dd -11
aa:
dd 0
start:
goto00:
        invoke GetStdHandle, [h]
        invoke gotoxy,eax,[pos00]
        push dword [aa]
        push str2
        call [printf]
        inc dword [aa]
        jmp start
data import
     library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', \
             msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
     import kernel32, \
            exit,'ExitProcess',\
            gotoxy, 'SetConsoleCursorPosition',\
            GetStdHandle,'GetStdHandle'
     import msvcrt,\
            printf,'printf'
end data
```

Comment: Try `add esp, 8` after the call to printf.

Comment: will you tell me a reason? thanks! it doesn't crash now

Comment: In a word, "calling convention". The Windows API is "stdcall" - callee cleans up stack. But C (printf) is "cdecl" - caller cleans up stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:**

```
format PE console
entry start
include 'win32a.inc'
pos00:
db 10,0,0,0
str2:
db '%d',0
h:
dd -11
aa:
dd 0
start:
goto00:
        invoke GetStdHandle, [h]
        invoke gotoxy,eax,[pos00]
        push dword [aa]
        push str2
        call [printf]
        add esp, 8
        inc dword [aa]
        jmp start
data import
     library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', \
             msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
     import kernel32, \
            exit,'ExitProcess',\
            gotoxy, 'SetConsoleCursorPosition',\
            GetStdHandle,'GetStdHandle'
     import msvcrt,\
            printf,'printf'
end data
```